# Is "main" method of spring boot application required when deploy as war

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

When we deploy the spring boot application as a "war" on tomcat, we have to extend SpringBootServletInitializer and override the “configure” method.
When I comment "main" method, it still works and spring boot application  and my services work fine. Do we still need main method when deploy project as "war" and why?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWs
public class TestApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
builder) {
        return builder.sources(TestApp.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWs
public class TestApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
builder) {
        return builder.sources(TestApp.class);
    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't because nobody will ever call it.

Expect for the case if you want to run it outside of the web container.

Comment: okay,then who runs spring application(i.e. who calls SpringApplication.run)?

Comment: That's done in by the Servlet of SpringBootServletInitializer